# Rabl caching with nested object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rabl

Here are my rabl views:

**students/show.json.rabl**

```
object @student
cache @student
attribute :name, :gender, :age

node :school do |student|
  partial("shared/school", :object => student.school)
end
```

**shared/_school.json.rabl**

```
object @school
cache @school

attributes :id, :name
```

**student.rb:**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :school, :touch => true

end
```

**school.rb**

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :students

end
```

So when I update a student, the cache gets invalidated as expected. The problem is that when I update a school, the students dont get the updated school attributes. I would have thought the cache @school in the partial would get invalidated when I update the school model but that doesn't seem to be the case.

**EDIT: Added touch to student to invalidate school on update.**

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of helping someone else, here is what I am doing now:

I split the student show view into:

**students/show.json.rabl:**

```
extends "students/min_show"

node :school do |student|
  partial("shared/school", :object => student.school)
end
```

**and students/min_show.json**

```
object @student
cache @student
attribute :name, :gender, :age
```

This way I still read the cache for student but the school is always rendered from the template and is cached separately.

Answer (score 1):

You need to auto expire the `School` cache when `Student` is updated:

> class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> ```
> belongs_to :school, :touch => true
> ```
>
> end

Comment: That definitely works if student is updated. But it doesnt work the other way around when School is updated. Basically, I am looking for a way to do 2 cache reads, one for student(s) and one for each school.

Answer (score 0):

I left a comment on your issue where I recommend to nest students under school. An easy workaround that should work for you is:

```
cache [@student, @student.school]
```

This way it checks the cache_key on both objects.